# When will a newer Cartopy version appear in official anaconda distro?

Tags: cartopy

I know I can install from conda-forge, but when will a newer Cartopy version appear in the Anaconda repository? Current version is 0.16.0. Is this determined by the Anaconda or the Cartopy team?

Answer (score 0):

The cartopy developers have no determination in what is packaged in Anaconda unfortunately (though a number of the cartopy developers have collaborated with the Anaconda folks a lot).

Issues with Anaconda can be raised on their tracker at https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues, but note that there are a **lot** of issues on that tracker so YMMV. If you have a support contract contacting support@continuum.io can apparently speed things up.

Comment: Thanks pelson.  I don't think I'll bother cluttering up their tracker.